# How to integrate Parse.com and SDWebImage?

Tags: ios

It seems that Parse.com is not compatible with the Other Linker Flag "-ObjC". However, SDWebImage requires that flag. How can you resolve? I read that "-force_load" can be used. However, I haven't figured out how to make it work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? (in other linker flags):

-force_load $(PROJECT_DIR)/SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage